# Specify a network interface with curl

Tags: networking, routing, curl

For some reasons, i want to code a proxy server that route its requests through its wifi interface instead of ethernet (which is the default route on the OS level). I know i could do that by fiddling with os routes but i would prefer to do it directly in curl for instance.

I have read that you actually can choose the network interface a socket will use with the --interface option but it doesn't seem to work for me :(

I tried the following:

`curl --interface wlp2s0 google.com`

But i only get ETIMEDOUT errors.. 
On the other hand if i do

`curl --interface enp0s20 google.com`

it works as expected..

Does anyone has a clue what is going on ?

Comment: `ETIMEDOUT` means the request was sent - but the server did not respond.. I just tried, and this worked for me no problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by *Matt Clark*, *ETIMEDOUT* means you could not reach the specified site, for whichever reason.

But let me also point out you misinterpret the meaning of the *--interface* option. What it means is: if I have two or more interfaces, use the IP address of the interface that I specify, rather than the default one". But as for routing, *i.e.*, deciding which interface the request is routed thru, it is **the kernel** that decides, not your command, according to the routing table you have: if the routing table specifies a default gateway over *eth0*, for instance, the *curl* request will  be routed thru it even though you have specified *--interface wlan0*.

Let's check this: I have set up two *tcpdump* sessions, one on my ethernet device (*usb0*), one on the wifi device (*wlan0*); both are connected, but the routing table has the gateway over *usb0*. Now, in a third shell, I send two *curl* requests, as follows:

```
$ date && curl --interface usb0 146.255.36.1/plain
mar 22 nov 2016, 18.44.21, CET
<!-- pageok -->
<!-- managed by puppet -->
<html>
<pre>pageok</pre>
</html>
$ date && curl --interface wlan0 146.255.36.1/plain
mar 22 nov 2016, 18.44.44, CET
<!-- pageok -->
<!-- managed by puppet -->
<html>
<pre>pageok</pre>
</html>
```

and this is what my two *tcpdump* sessions record: the one on wifi

```
# tcpdump -i wlan0 -n host 146.255.36.1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

and the one on ethernet

```
# tcpdump -i usb0 -n host 146.255.36.1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on usb0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
18:44:21.118505 IP 192.168.73.74.52601 > 146.255.36.1.80: Flags [S], seq 2178801514, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 10527374 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:44:21.147291 IP 146.255.36.1.80 > 192.168.73.74.52601: Flags [S.], seq 95036242, ack 2178801515, win 14480, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,TS val 500605800 ecr 10527374,nop,wscale 8], length 0
18:44:21.147322 IP 192.168.73.74.52601 > 146.255.36.1.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10527381 ecr 500605800], length 0
18:44:21.147375 IP 192.168.73.74.52601 > 146.255.36.1.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:82, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10527381 ecr 500605800], length 81: HTTP: GET /plain HTTP/1.1
18:44:21.175829 IP 146.255.36.1.80 > 192.168.73.74.52601: Flags [.], ack 82, win 57, options [nop,nop,TS val 500605829 ecr 10527381], length 0
18:44:21.178222 IP 146.255.36.1.80 > 192.168.73.74.52601: Flags [P.], seq 1:285, ack 82, win 57, options [nop,nop,TS val 500605832 ecr 10527381], length 284: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
18:44:21.178236 IP 192.168.73.74.52601 > 146.255.36.1.80: Flags [.], ack 285, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 10527389 ecr 500605832], length 0
18:44:21.178321 IP 192.168.73.74.52601 > 146.255.36.1.80: Flags [F.], seq 82, ack 285, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 10527389 ecr 500605832], length 0
18:44:21.206618 IP 146.255.36.1.80 > 192.168.73.74.52601: Flags [F.], seq 285, ack 83, win 57, options [nop,nop,TS val 500605860 ecr 10527389], length 0
18:44:21.206642 IP 192.168.73.74.52601 > 146.255.36.1.80: Flags [.], ack 286, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 10527396 ecr 500605860], length 0
18:44:44.284057 IP 192.168.73.45.41804 > 146.255.36.1.80: Flags [S], seq 2817430695, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 10533165 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:44:44.313090 IP 146.255.36.1.80 > 192.168.73.45.41804: Flags [S.], seq 3652186052, ack 2817430696, win 14480, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,TS val 500628966 ecr 10533165,nop,wscale 8], length 0
18:44:44.313117 IP 192.168.73.45.41804 > 146.255.36.1.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10533172 ecr 500628966], length 0
18:44:44.313152 IP 192.168.73.45.41804 > 146.255.36.1.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:82, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10533172 ecr 500628966], length 81: HTTP: GET /plain HTTP/1.1
18:44:44.342243 IP 146.255.36.1.80 > 192.168.73.45.41804: Flags [.], ack 82, win 57, options [nop,nop,TS val 500628995 ecr 10533172], length 0
18:44:44.343076 IP 146.255.36.1.80 > 192.168.73.45.41804: Flags [P.], seq 1:285, ack 82, win 57, options [nop,nop,TS val 500628996 ecr 10533172], length 284: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
18:44:44.343090 IP 192.168.73.45.41804 > 146.255.36.1.80: Flags [.], ack 285, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 10533180 ecr 500628996], length 0
18:44:44.343168 IP 192.168.73.45.41804 > 146.255.36.1.80: Flags [F.], seq 82, ack 285, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 10533180 ecr 500628996], length 0
18:44:44.372262 IP 146.255.36.1.80 > 192.168.73.45.41804: Flags [F.], seq 285, ack 83, win 57, options [nop,nop,TS val 500629025 ecr 10533180], length 0
18:44:44.372302 IP 192.168.73.45.41804 > 146.255.36.1.80: Flags [.], ack 286, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 10533187 ecr 500629025], length 0
^C
20 packets captured
20 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Notice:

1. The time stamps, corresponding to each request,
2. the different LAN Ip addresses, 192.168.73.74 for ethernet and 192.168.73.45 for wifi.
3. That **all** packets are detected by the *tcpdump* session on the ethernet interface, irrespective of my choice of *--interface*.

You may ask: so when is the *--interface* option useful? When you have two (or more) routing tables, one per each interface, each with its own **gateway**. Then *--interface* allows you to specify which interface is used to reach *curl*'s destination. If you want to know more about how to setup up *policy routing*, you may read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22794/49626).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I really am clueless when it comes to networking. Your link is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @cp2587 *I really am clueless when it comes to networking*: do not worry, we have all been there. :-)